# SQL Query sorted by date

Tags: sql, database

looking for query help on this. what would be the query for the below results.

List of all apartments that were occupied on March 1, 2015 sorted by complex and apartment number.

```
ComplexName ApartmentNumber
-----------------------------
Fox Run        101
Fox Run        102
Fox Run        204
Oak Meadows    103
Villa Maria     11
Villa Maria     12
```

List of all tenants that had a current lease on March 1, 2015 sorted by property and apartment number

Example results:

```
ComplexName ApartmentNumber GivenName   FamilyName
----------------------------------------------------------
Fox Run       101            Shannon    McCoy
Fox Run       102              Larry    Thomas
Fox Run       204               Mark    Patterson
Oak Meadows   103               Jose    Ortiz
Villa Maria    11             Cassie    Lee
Villa Maria    12             Robert    Woodward
```

Sum of all rent paid in 2015 grouped by property and month
Example results:

```
ComplexName     Month    Rent Revenue
--------------------------------------
Fox Run         March     1250.00    
Oak Meadows     March     1500.00    
Oak Meadows     April      700.00    
Villa Maria     March     1200.00    
Villa Maria     April      600.00
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service - what have you tried? what is the problem with it? Please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you table names and column names, it is difficult to give advice without these: For example if your table was called apartments and had a column occupieddate and appartment number

```
SELECT * 
FROM Apartments 
WHERE 
    occupieddate ='03/01/2015' 
ORDER BY
    Appartment number;
```

Could be an answer to your first question

Comment: select complex.ComplexNameKey, apartment.ApartmentNumber
from apartment
inner join complex
on apartment.Complex_ComplexKey = complex.ComplexKey
order by ComplexName ASC;

I have this so far, this gives all the apartment and complexes, I need to sort them by date now